# Is it possible to integrate Google services and Mobile Me?

Tags: gmail, synchronization, mac, mobileme, iphone

I'm an avid GMail user, but as someone that has several Macs and an iPhone, I've had my eye on the Mobile Me service for a while as it provides push syncing for mail, contacts, and calendar, as well as other services like Back to my Mac and Find my iPhone. The only sticking point for me is getting it to work well with GMail. I currently use [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/) which works well enough on my iPhone, but does not work with my Mac.

The easiest option would be to forward my GMail to my Mobile Me account, but the downside is that any replies I send will have my @me.com return address instead of my @gmail.com address.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought I read about that as a feature of MobileMe, but I just looked and cannot find it.  Have you signed up for a trial yet?

Comment: @Jim I did 2 years ago, and unfortunately I don't remember much... and I can't do another one because they need a different CC#

Comment: a good alternative is just to go to an Apple store and ask. Chances are a Genius will answer your question in 5 mins or less. Its like OCD for them ,its either it cannot be done or if can it can be done they will know how *and will not let you leave until they give you an answer*

Comment: I am going to the Apple store today, so I will have an answer by then.  If it does support GMail, etc. then I will sign up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the Genius at the **Genius Bar** today, and they had to ask around, but there is a new feature in the latest MobileMe that allows specifically that.  Have your MobileMe consolidate all your email into that account, then you use an "alias" that lets you send as any of those accounts.  Looks like there is a limit of 5 aliases.

Here is some information on it:

- [Create or edit an alias](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=MobileMe/Help/en/mm6b1a3de6.html)
- [Creating an alias](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=MobileMe/Mail/en/ml17008.html)
- [Sending email using an alias](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=MobileMe/Mail/en/ml17017.html)
- [Using an external email account](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4222)

That should get you going.  I am signing up for MobileMe too.  Sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gmail's exchange server support for email and Calendar syncing.

Follow these [instructions](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) from Google.

Comment: Ah, thought the OP was looking to stick with MobileMe for email/calendar/contacts - giving a +1 to using Gmail's ActiveSync to keep your iPhone in sync (via push) with your Google Gmail, Calendar and contacts.

Personally, I use ActiveSync for Calendar-push only, IMAP for Gmail (don't need/want push) and MobileMe for Contacts & Find My Phone

Comment: Personally I use it for gmail and calendar, I use CalDav to keep my Mac calendars synced with google calendars.  You forward your mobileMe email to gmail if you want to use the gmail interface while not on your phone, or visa versa if you want to use the mobileMe/Mail app.  This is my exact setup and I can send/receive from any of the clients and I have it all nicely on my iPhone.  Calendars are all synced and updated via the cloud.  It really is a beautiful thing.  It has taken iOS4 to get it all working perfectly, but now that we are here I am finally happy.

Answer (score 0):

The latest revision to MobileMe lets you send email "from" an alternate address/account:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4222

You can set up your gmail account to forward to your me.com address or enable POP access and let MobileMe check it via POP (that won't provide true "push" functionality however...)

This should support exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I also have several Macs and an iPhone, and I use both Google services and Mobile Me.  They actually work very well together if you primarily use local apps such as Mail, iCal, and Address Book, instead of the web apps.  Since both services' email, calendar, and address book features are standards based, you can mix and match features from the two providers, and everything flows smoothly.  I use Google's email and calendar, but Apple's contacts.  When composing an email, Mail pulls auto-complete options from Address Book's data store, and doesn't care one bit that it's from a different provider than my email.

I've been using this combination for quite a while now, and I really like it.  Both services have plenty of unique features (Where's my iPhone and native bookmark syncing from Mobile Me, Reader and Docs from Google).  Where the services overlap, I just use whichever one I like best.